# MongoDB Array Size Condition in Query

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I currently have a simple condition query for MongoDB that goes like this:

```js
{
    "$and": [
        {
            "ApplicationStatus": "UW_SECOND_LEVEL"
        },
        {
            "Application.UnderWriterDecisions.ud_cc_total_aggregate_limit": {
                "$lte": 300000, "$gt":100000
            }
        },
        {
            "Application.UnderWriterDecisions.UW_Recon_Count": {
                "$eq": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add another condition to the query above that checks the size of an array (`DecisionReason`) that I have, and make sure that it only has a size of 1:

`Application.UnderwriterDecisions.DecisionReason`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$size` operator. Also, you don't have to use the explicit `$and` operator, but just separate the clauses with commas. From [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) in the documentation.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

Also, you do not need to use the `$eq` operator, so your final query would look something like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "ApplicationStatus": "UW_SECOND_LEVEL",
    "Application.UnderWriterDecisions.ud_cc_total_aggregate_limit":
        { "$lte": 300000, "$gt": 100000 },
    "Application.UnderWriterDecisions.UW_Recon_Count": null,
    "Application.UnderWriterDecisions.DecisionReason":
        { "$size": 1 }
});
```

For more information about the `$size` operator, check out [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Juan. I read about the $size operator yesterday, but found trouble on how to actually include it in my existing query. I've tried what you've suggested, and I'm to say that my query is working properly now with the array size condition. Thank you for the help! Appreciate it a ton!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad it helped you out.